# Laravel eloquent multiple has and where clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
Employee::has("tags")->orHas("Categories")->where("employeeName","LIKE","seo%")->get();
```

I have two belongsToMany relationship which is tags and Categories. 
Mutiple has clause works unless I put where clause after.

How can I use has clause with where ??

I need help !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
Employee::where(function($q) {
  $q->has("tags")->orHas("Categories");
})->where("employeeName","LIKE","seo%")->get();
```

because you need to have brackets in your query to get what you expect