# how can do a multiple has() /orHas() in laravel 5.4 orm

Tags: php, orm, laravel-5.4

First of all I should say I want to Use laravel ORM not query builder and not the Raw sql methods. so here is my question.

I have a model called bots that has `belongTo(User::class)` relation and 6 `hasMany(TextPost::class)` - `hasMany(PhotoPost::class)` and so on. I want to get bots that has at least one record in any of the `hasMany(...)` relations. so if a bot has a record in `TextPost` it should be returned and if a bot has no post in none of the `hasMany(...)` relations it should not be returned.

so far I have something like this in my `User` model

```
    public function broadCasters()
    {
        return $this->bots->has('text_post')->orHas('photo_post')->orHas('media_post')->orHas('video_post')->orHas('audio_post')->orHas('document_post');
    }
```

but its not going to work and says `Call to a member function orHas() on boolean`

so I wanted to change it to something like this:

```
public function broadCasters(){
  return $this->bots->where(function($query){
    return $query->has('TextPost')->orHas('PhotoPost') ...;
  });
}
```

but this is not gonna work either and says `Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::where()`. what should I do?

I use laravel 5.4. bu I saw this Question [whereHas on multiple relationships - laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069649/wherehas-on-multiple-relationships-laravel-5-4) and its pretty close to what I want but no answers yet!!

also this question is another of my questions too, [Combining AND/OR eloquent query in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653216/combining-and-or-eloquent-query-in-laravel)

but its not working either.

AND NOW THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I WANT BUT NOT WORKING, I THINK BECAUSE ITS FOR LARAVEL 4 AND I USE LARAVEL 5.4

[Laravel eloquent multiple has and where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513518/laravel-eloquent-multiple-has-and-where-clause)

Comment: $reqObj->where(function($q){$q->has('group');$q->orHas('group_member');}); seems to be working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

enter code hereIf you user `$this->bots`, the result will be laravel collection array. You need to use `$this->bots()` like this :

```
public function broadCasters(){
  return $this->bots()->where(function($query){
    return $query->has('TextPost')->orHas('PhotoPost') ...;
  })->get();
}
```